# Node js vs Apache Tomcat container

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js and built my first app helloworld.js. I know java and tomcat architecture well. But I have some questions:

1. I wonder how to create a second web-app that always responds on the
   same port but with different url.

For example
http://localhost:3000/ 
http://localhost:3000/app1/
http://localhost:3000/app2/

2. I saw that there are different ways to access the various db. In the
   node js world there is something like hibernate that makes the dbms
   transparent to the programmer?
3. There is something like tiles and tag library to build html page?

Answer (score 0):

In order:

1. Unless you use `nginx` or some other reverse proxy, that is not possible. However, you can run different applications on different ports like `3001`, `3002` etc, and run a server which acts as an intermediary between your client and these servers at port 3000.
2. Depends on framework to framework.
3. I am not familiar with `tiles and tag`, but in nodejs land, you can use `ejs`, `handlebars` or `jade` to design templates.